# Angular Material Table | Add Remove rows at runtime

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using [Angular Material Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) that is backed by a plain array as the data source.

```
this.employees = this.route.snapshot.data.employes; // of type Employee[] resolved using a Resolve guard
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Employee>(this.employees);
```

Once rendered initially, I want to add/remove rows from the data table by modifying the 'this.employess' array using method in my component :-

```
addEmployee(e: Employee){
 this.employess.push(e);   // I expect the table to have one row added after this.
}

removeEmployee(index : number){
  // splice the array at given index & remove one row from data table
}
```

**PROBLEM**

The data table rows are not affected when I add remove elements in my array. 
I found an a [blog](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/#datasourcesandthedatatablereactivedesign) elaborating same problem but uses a custom data source.  Is there any way using plain array ?

Comment: Angular doesn't detect changes on objects, including arrays, because the array reference doesn't change when add or delete elements on it.

Answer (score 16):

The Simplest way is to  call _updateChangeSubscription() on your dataSource as you are already using MatTableDataSource

> this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.employees);

Your new modified addEmployee method will become:

```
addEmployee(e: Employee){
 this.employess.push(e);   // I expect the table to have one row added after this.
 this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription()  // THIS WILL DO
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Though I accessed the mat datasource directly by `this.datasource.data` instead of using an own array to host the data. I pushed to that list by calling `this.datasource.data.push()`

Answer (score 11):

In Latest versions of **Angular Material 7/8**

You need to call **.renderRows()** method after pushing new row data

```
addRowData(row_obj){
   var d = new Date();
   this.dataSource.push({
     id:d.getTime(),
     name:row_obj.name
   });
   this.table.renderRows();
 }

 deleteRowData(row_obj){
    this.dataSource = this.dataSource.filter((value,key)=>{
      return value.id != row_obj.id;
    });
 }
```

**Source Tutorial [link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-8-edit-add-delete-rows-in-material-table-with-using-dialogs-inline-row-operation/)**

[image]

Comment: I get an error if I try to use this.dataSource.push with Angular 7 and latest materials - I need to use this.dataSource.data.push

Answer (score 3):

The problem is angular/ Mat-table does not detect any modifications to the underlying array after it has been instantiated. Hence, if you choose to add or delete a row you have to explicitly make the table listen to the event or just refresh the tables data. Below is how you would do it.

```
addEmployee(e: Employee){
 this.employess.push(e);   // I expect the table to have one row added after this.
 this.dataSource.data = this.employees; // this step will refresh the table
}
```

Same would be the case with your remove method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class `EmployeeDataSource` that takes an `Observable<Employee[]>` instead of `Employee[]` :

```
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class EmployeeListDataSource extends DataSource<any> {


    constructor(private _employeeList$: Observable<Employee[]>) {
        super();
    }

    connect(): Observable<Employee[]> {
        return this._employeeList$;
    }

    disconnect() {
    }
}
```

Then create your data source by passing an observable :

```
this.dataSource = new EmployeeListDataSource(yourObservable);
```

[You can find a stackblitz example here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49172970)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but you could create a subject in which you store your data. Now you can use it just like the blogpost.

```
public $data: BehaviorSubject<MyDataType[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

addEmployee(e: Employee){
    this.$data
      .first()
      .subscribe(data => {
          let newData = data.slice();
          newData.push(e);
          this.$data.next(newData);
      }
}
```

Comment: With a behavior subject there is no need to subscribe if you want to access the current value of it, just use `$data.value`. Although I remember this being labeled as an anti-pattern somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular 9, Here what i have done

```
this.dataSource.data.push({
      profile:"profile",
      skillRequired:"skillRequired"
    });
this.dataSource.filter = "";
```

using filter datatable automatically gets updated